# Is it possible to force current robot position on the map (like the initial_pose of the navigation stack)?

Tags: slam, navigation, force, hector-slam, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does hector_slam have the capability to accept the current robot position on the map as input, like the initial_pose topic that the navigation stack subscribes to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12784/is-it-possible-to-force-current-robot-position-on-the-map-(like-the-initial_pose-of-the-navigation-stack)?/) by [matthieu nottale](https://answers.ros.org/users/1703/matthieu-nottale/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not at the moment, but I'll look into adding this in the next days. In the meantime, you can control the start pose via the parameters

```
map_start_x
map_start_y
```

as described in the [parameter description](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping#Parameters).
Do you want to set the start position and perform a map reset, or do you want to sort of manually correct the pose, keeping the map learned so far?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthieu nottale](https://answers.ros.org/users/1703/matthieu-nottale/) on 2012-01-31**:
That's the idea. This feature is an absolute requirement when trying to use SLAM in real use cases according to our experience. One that would be nice is a "relocalize" feature that would try to find the most probable robot position without a priori given a map and laser data.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-31**:
I see, so ideally one would want to be able to switch off the mapping process and only resume once the initial pose ist set. I'll see if find the time to implement that :)

**Comment by [matthieu nottale](https://answers.ros.org/users/1703/matthieu-nottale/) on 2012-01-31**:
I'd like to reset  the position while keeping the map. Useful when the robot is moved by the operator, or stopped and restarted at an other place.

**Comment by [jdelbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2007/jdelbe/) on 2012-06-07**:
+1 for the feature request. It is a must have in our case as well.